# cmd $env:APPDATA - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: command-line, cmd

I've been having this issue for awhile now, and I don't know why. Simply trying to do `cd $env:APPDATA` but it throws a message saying that it can't find the path.

Also the mv command doesn't work as well. It just returns that 'mv' is not a recognized as an internal or external command.

Any ideas?

Here's my path var - C:\Ruby200\bin\; C:\Windows\System32\

So I don't see anything wrong with that... Any ideas?

Comment: Well the `APPDATA` variable is looking at C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Roaming\. Are you running the shell as a system/service user that does not have a roaming profile..?

Comment: Yes I'm running cmd as am admin. Powershell sees env as a drive so it sees the variable. I just thought cmd would also see it.

Comment: So are you running the command in PowerShell or Windows CMD?

Comment: I'm running Windows CMD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell uses `$env:APPDATA` to access the environment variable for the user's roaming profile, as you know and are use to.

To do the same thing in Windows CMD however it would look like this:

```
cd %APPDATA%
```

See [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) for reference.